# CrossMapLRN2d in pytorch

Tags: keras, pytorch, normalization

I had to convert a code written in pytorch to keras (with tensorflow backend). But there was this layer called CrossMapLRN2d which had no direct counterpart in Keras. So wanted to know what does this layer do and how to implement it in keras.
The exact line of code was

```
nn.CrossMapLRN2d(size=5, alpha=0.0001, beta=0.75, k=1.0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Local (contrast) normalization**

Local Response Normalization (LRN) layer implements the lateral inhibition we were talking about in the previous section. This layer is useful when we are dealing with ReLU neurons. **Why is that?** Because ReLU neurons have unbounded activations and we need LRN to normalize that. We want to detect high frequency features with a large response. If we normalize around the local neighborhood of the excited neuron, it becomes even more sensitive as compared to its neighbor.

**2 options in keras**. First it is already implemented [check here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/97174dd298cf4b5be459e79b0181a124650d9148/keras/layers/normalization.py#L66) but thats "old" keras. New, Google implementation can be [found here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/local_response_normalization?version=stable)

Comment: what does crossmap stand for in the name

Comment: I suspect some architecture specific property, dont know for sure.